# How to get this thread waiting on a queue to quit?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I've got two threads in my application. One that puts values in a [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html), and another that pulls them from the `Queue` and processes them.

I am faced with a dilemma when shutting the application down. The thread that processes items in the `Queue` is stuck on:

```
item = request_queue.get() # this call blocks until an item is available
```

The only thing that will terminate the thread is if another item is added to the `Queue` - and since the main thread doesn't add anything (because it's shutting down), the application locks.

So... how can I instruct `Queue.get()` to somehow return even if there is nothing on the `Queue`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer it turns out is quite simple. Pick a value that would be invalid for the code that processes the `Queue` (`None` is ideal for that) and push that into the `Queue`. Then have the `Queue` processing thread quit when it gets the value:

```
while True:

    item = request_queue.get()

    if item is None:
        break

    # process the Queue as per normal...
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if multiple worker threads add `None` to queue, then account for that when removing items from the queue. For example, if nones_found == 2: break (adjust 2 to number of times None is added).

Answer (score 1):

Since the blocking thread is not the main thread, you could also set `.daemon = True`.

```
import time
import threading
from Queue import Queue

def getter(q):
    while True:
        print 'getting...'
        print q.get(), 'gotten'

def putter(q):
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        q.put(i)
        time.sleep(0.5)

q = Queue()
get_thread = threading.Thread(target=getter, args=(q,))
get_thread.daemon = True
get_thread.start()

putter(q)
```

Comment: I could... but that would result in an unclean shutdown of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can still occur if Queue.get() is called in the main thread - so the setDaemon(True) answer is not a universal solution.

For example this script cannot be stopped with Ctrl-C

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Queue

theQ = Queue.Queue()
print "one thread getting from Queue"
print theQ.get()
```

Rather than putting a timeout on Queue.get() and dealing with exceptions, a simple solution is to do a wait loop until something is there. This script can be killed with Ctrl-C

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Queue
theQ = Queue.Queue()
print "one thread getting from Queue"
while theQ.empty():
    time.sleep(0.01) # or whatever value is appropriate for your event arrivals
print theQ.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check queue size and wait a specific time before exiting queue, so that you know more data items are not being added at the time of exiting.

```
last_obj_time = time.time()
while True:
    if request_queue.qsize() > 0:
        item = request_queue.get()
        last_obj_time = time.time()

    elif time.time() - last_obj_time > 10:
        break
```

Comment: [Busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) is almost always a bad solution to these kinds of problems. You will just be actively wasting energy and compute power, when there are other means available.